# Парольная политика Linux

Tags: linux, пароль

В Linux есть конфигурационный файл, где настраиваются требования к паролям - /etc/security/pwquality.conf.

Есть требования:
Длина пароля минимум 14 символов
Пароль образован из цифр, строчных и прописных букв
В пароле используется минимум 6 разных символов
В пароле отсутствуют три рядом стоящих знака.

Как реализовать данное требование?

Все man page уже читал, руководства в том числе. Нужна конкретная настройка требований

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: а мануал уже читал? Вполне возможно, что там есть вся необходимая информация

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/5/pwquality.conf

Comment: @Эникейщик Да, уже успел мануал вычитать много раз, но настройка все равно не проходит...

Comment: всервно найдется тот кто сделает sudo passwd user 123 123